# Hacer la media de las columna en lotes de 5 filas empleando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe que contiene datos de un conjunto de pruebas que he realizado. Y ahora me gustaría hacer la media de las columnas. El problema, es que quiero hacer la media en lotes de 5 filas. Es decir, coger las primeras 5 filas y obtener el valor medio para cada columna, las 5 siguientes y lo mismo...

Básicamente quiero esto porque si os fijáis la segunda fila es `KFold`, que va de 0 a 4 (5 filas) y estas 5 filas son el mismo experimento/prueba repetido 5 veces, por lo tanto si hago la media de estos 5, tengo el resultado general de este experimento.

A continuación dejo un ejemplo de mi dataframe:

```
Index Code  kFold   Epochs  Batch size  Loss    LR  Optimizer   Train Loss  Val Loss    Train Acc (%)   Val Acc (%) Train Prec. (%) Val Prec (%)    Train Recall (%)    Val Recall (%)  VN  FN  FP  VP  Train time (segs)
0   Feat_1  0   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adam    0.0528  0.0588  98.1    98.0    94.2    96.1    96.0    93.9    464 7   6   76  25.5910
1   Feat_2  1   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adam    0.0552  0.0996  98.1    97.6    93.0    93.7    95.7    91.5    461 10  9   73  24.6834
2   Feat_3  2   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adam    0.0499  0.0902  98.3    97.3    93.9    91.4    97.6    92.7    459 12  7   75  25.2233
3   Feat_4  3   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adam    0.0485  0.0934  98.1    97.1    93.7    90.1    95.7    92.7    462 9   9   73  25.8720
4   Feat_5  4   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adam    0.0522  0.0788  98.1    97.3    94.3    92.4    96.0    92.8    461 9   10  73  25.3213
5   Feat_6  0   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adamax  0.0686  0.0608  97.5    98.0    92.3    96.1    93.0    91.5    467 4   9   73  24.6431
6   Feat_7  1   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adamax  0.0680  0.1099  97.6    96.6    92.0    90.9    92.4    89.0    461 10  11  71  24.7920
7   Feat_8  2   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adamax  0.0605  0.0881  97.6    96.9    100.0   88.2    93.0    92.7    460 11  7   75  24.5452
8   Feat_9  3   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adamax  0.0616  0.0965  97.7    97.1    92.9    89.3    93.0    91.5    461 10  8   74  24.6338
9   Feat_10 4   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 Adamax  0.0637  0.0819  97.7    96.9    93.1    92.3    93.6    86.7    463 7   12  71  24.9663
10  Feat_11 0   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 SGD 0.1959  0.1868  91.8    92.4    73.7    74.1    71.1    75.6    449 22  20  62  24.9848
11  Feat_12 1   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 SGD 0.1908  0.2067  92.2    90.4    100.0   100.0   72.9    67.1    445 26  27  55  26.8961
12  Feat_13 2   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 SGD 0.1911  0.2019  92.2    90.6    100.0   70.6    72.9    69.5    444 27  25  57  24.4316
13  Feat_14 3   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 SGD 0.1928  0.1960  91.9    91.9    73.4    76.1    71.4    68.3    452 19  26  56  24.5151
14  Feat_15 4   2212    1100    binary_crossentropy 0.1 SGD 0.1953  0.1874  91.7    92.9    100.0   79.7    70.7    71.1    453 17  24  59  25.7131
```

EDIT: Añado una foto por si no se lee bien, que se pueda ver cómodamente (son los mismos datos).

[image]

La verdad que no tengo mucho código que poner, pues el problema es saber si puedo o no hacerlo. Se que existe la función `mean()` y que con el atributo `axis=0` defino que quiero trabajar las filas, pero no se como hacerlo.

¡¡Un saludo y muchas gracias!!

Comment: Ojo `a1/n + a2/n + ... aj/n = (a1 + a2 + ... + aj)/n` con n constante (en este caso 5), no vas a obtener un resultado diferente de que obtendrías haciendo directamente la media de la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso lo mejor sería usar el `groupby()` de pandas junto con `mean()` ya que querras ver cual de tus optimizadores es mejor (Stochastic Gradient Descend o Adaptive Moment Estimation), aunque parece a simple vista que **Adam es el mejor**. El código de ejemplo para hacerlo sería el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9,3), columns=['peso', 'altura', 'actividad'])
df_matrix['tipo'] = ['virus']*3 + ['bacteria']*3 + ['celula'] *3

print(df_matrix.groupby(['tipo']).mean())
```

He generado una matriz (9,3) aleatoria, luego le he agregado una columna llamada "tipo" y por último he hecho la media según el tipo. En el `groupby()` tienes que seleccionar la columna que quieres hacer la media, que en tu caso será **Optimizer**.

Esta operación lo que hará será agrupar todas las columnas por el tipo de opitimizador y luego hacer la media.

Te recomiendo ver la documentación de Pandas sobre el `groupby()`, es una de las  mejores funciones y más poderosas de pandas, que te quita mucho trabajo si sabes usarla. te dejo [aquí la documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: MARAVILLOSO! Muchas gracias, al final lo he agrupado por Optimizador y Learning Rate, `df.groupby(['Optimizer','LR']).mean()`

Comment: Sí! dentro de la lista del ```groupby()``` puedes introducir todas las columnas que desees! Es parecido a  un ```GROUP BY```  de SQL. De nada, me alegro que te haya servido!